# Couldn't find SoundBoard without an ID (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to make a review/rating function for my soundboard rails app, 
but whenever I click on the link to add a new review/rating I get an error of

> Couldn't find SoundBoard without an ID

at @sound_board = SoundBoard.find(params[:sound_board_id])

Any help?

controllers/sound_board_ratings_controller.rb

```
class SoundboardRatingsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_rating, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :set_sound_board

.
.
.
private
  def set_sound_board
    @sound_board = SoundBoard.find(params[:sound_board_id])
  end
```

routes.rb

```
  match "/sound_board_ratings/new", to: "sound_board_ratings#new", :via => 'get'
  resources :sound_board do
     resources :sound_board_ratings
  end
```

sound_board_ratings/new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for([@sound_board, @sound_board_rating]) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <div id="rating"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :comment %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :comment %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

sound_board/show.html.erb

```
.
.
.
        <% if user_signed_in? %>
                  <%= link_to "Pate this SoundBoard", sound_board_ratings_new_path(@sound_board), class: "button round" %>
                  <% @sound_board_ratings.each do |sound_board_rating| %>
                      <div class="rating" data-score= <%= sound_board_rating.rating %> ></div>
                      <p><%= sound_board_rating.comment %></p>
                <% end %>
        <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to `set_soundboard_id` before *all* actions.  Just for ones where you have an ID in the params to lookup.  So you could:

```
before_action :set_sound_board, except: [:index, :new, :create]
```

Comment: I managed to get to the "new" page with the form to rating by doing this, but when I submit the form, I get the same error. Any idea why?

Comment: Yes.  You won't have an ID yet for the `:create` action either.  So add that to the `except` list

Answer (score 0):

You can do this (slight tweak to @Daiku's suggestion)

```
before_action :set_sound_board, except: [:index, :new, :create]
```

You can also do this

```
@sound_board = SoundBoard.find_by_id(params[:sound_board_id])
```

Which will fail gracefully and set @soundboard to null.  I recommend Daiku's suggestion - just add the :create to the array.